# regex: trim all strings directly preceeded by digit except if string belongs to predefined set of strings

Tags: java, regex

I've got addresses I need to clean up for matching purposes. 
Part of the process is trimming unwanted suffices from housenumbers, e.g:

```
mainstreet 4a --> mainstreet 4.
```

However I don't want:

```
618 5th Ave SW  --> 618 5 Ave SW
```

in other words there are some strings (for now: st, nd, rd, th) which I don't want to strip. 
What would be the best method of doing this (regex or otherwise) ?

a wokring regex without the exceptions would be:

```
a = a.replaceAll("(^| )([0-9]+)[a-z]+($| )","$1$2$3"); //replace 1a --> 1
```

I thought about first searching and substiting the special cases with special characters while keeping the references in a map, then do the above regex, and then doing the reverse substitute using the reference map, but I'm looking for a simpler solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do this with negative lookahead:

```
a = a.replaceAll("(^| )([0-9]+)(?!th|nd|etc)[a-z]+($| )","$1$2$3"); //replace 1a --> 1
```

or do it all with negative lookahead/lookbehind:

```
a = a.replaceAll("(?<=^| )([0-9]+)(?!th|nd|etc)[a-z]+(?= |$)", "$1"); //replace 1a --> 1 but not 2nd --> 2
```

Comment: Going with the first I think, bc. I can wrap by head around it.. Any advantage in using the latter? 

as an aside: how do you post with formatted code-examples?

Comment: I agree, it is a little easier to read the first :-). The second allows me to express just the part you want to match, and uses the zero-width lookahead/lookbehind/negative-lookahead to assert other things about where it appears, which is what they are meant for.

Comment: If you indent a line or paragraph with 4 spaces, it will be formatted as code. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more details on editing MarkDown.